# Confused AUC ROC score

Tags: classification, random-forest, logistic-regression, cross-validation, auc

I am working on binary classification problem, I try to evaluate the performance of some classification algorithms (**LR,Decission Tree , Random forest** ...).
I am using  a **cross validation** technique (to avoid over-fitting) with **AUC ROC** as scoring function to compare the performance of the algorithms, but I am getting a weird results with **Random forest** and **AdbBoost**, I have a perfect **AUC_ROC** score (i.e. =1) despite the fact that the recall(TPR) and FPR of this algorithms are different from 1 and 0 respectively .

[image]

```
def FPR(y_true, y_pred):
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
    result = fp / (fp+tn)
    return result
def FNR(y_true, y_pred):
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
    result = fn / (tp+fn)
    return result
FPR_scorer = make_scorer(FPR)
FNR_scorer = make_scorer(FNR)   

def get_CrossValResults2(model,cv_rst,bestIndx):
    best=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cv_rst).iloc[bestIndx]
    roc="{:.12f}".format(best['mean_test_roc_auc'])
    acc ="{:.0%}".format(best['mean_test_accuracy'])
    prec ="{:.0%}".format(best['mean_test_precision'])
    rec ="{:.0%}".format( best['mean_test_recall'])
    f1 ="{:.0%}".format(best['mean_test_f1'])
    r2="{:.2f}".format(best['mean_test_r2'])
    g_mean="{:.2f}".format(best['mean_test_gmean'])
    pr_auc="{:.8f}".format(best['mean_test_pr'])
    fnr="{:.0%}".format(best['mean_test_fnr'])
    fpr="{:.0%}".format(best['mean_test_fpr'])
    rst = pd.DataFrame([[ model, acc,prec,rec,fpr,fnr,f1,roc,pr_auc,g_mean,r2]],columns = ['Model', 'Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall','FPR','FNR', 'F1-Score','ROC_auc','PR_auc','gmean','r2'])
    return rst
      
cross_val_rst = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Model', 'Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall','FPR','FNR', 'F1-Score','ROC_auc','PR_auc','gmean','r2'])    
        
scoring = {'accuracy':'accuracy','recall':'recall','precision':'precision','fpr':FPR_scorer,'fnr':FNR_scorer,'f1':'f1' ,'roc_auc':'roc_auc','pr':'average_precision','gmean':Gmean_scorer,'r2':'r2'}    
param_grid = {'n_estimators': [200], 
             'max_depth': [80,90],
              'min_samples_leaf': [2,3, 4],
            'min_samples_split': [2,5,12],
            'criterion': [ 'gini'],
             'class_weight' : [class_weights], 'n_jobs' : [-1]} 
clf = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(class_weight=class_weights), param_grid, cv=kfold,scoring=scoring,refit=refit)#Fit the model
bestmodel = clf.fit(X,Y)
     
cross_val_rst = cross_val_rst.append(get_CrossValResults2(model='Random Forrest',bestIndx=bestmodel.best_index_,cv_rst=bestmodel.cv_results_),ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: With only two decimals, it may just be rounding.  Can you recover the actual value of ROC_auc?

Comment: cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478046/232706

Comment: The graphs you linked to in the comments to the answers are not very helpful.  What about the actual ROC plots?  What is the unrounded value of ROC_auc?

Comment: the values equals to 1.00000  https://imgur.com/6PmlMJ8

Comment: It seems likely that something is wrong then... the ROC curve for RF is missing at least the .04 by .03 rectangle in the upper-left, so AUC should be at most 1-0.04*0.03=0.9988.  Could you provide your code?

Comment: an answer was provided in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/346837/291828

Comment: That answer addresses accuracy<1, but not your TPR and FPR scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I think I've finally got it.  It's just an averaging problem: for each fold in your k-fold cross-validation, you get perfect auROC, but at the default threshold of 0.5 your hard classifiers (for each fold) sometimes have $FPR=0$ and $TPR<1$, but some other times $FPR>0$ and $TPR=1$.  Then averaging you are able to get both $\operatorname{mean}(FPR)>0$ and $\operatorname{mean}(TPR)<1$.

To check, have a look at the `cv_results_` table, particularly at each test fold scores (`split<i>_test_<xyz>`), rather than just the `mean_test_<xyz>` scores.

Answer (score 0):

I think recall and FPR are calculated in scikit-learn using a threshold of 0.5. On the other hand ROC AUC is transparent to model threshold. I encourage you to explore [thresholder in scikit-lego](https://scikit-lego.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta.html#Thresholder) to inspect in this direction.

An example of AUC = 1 but bad FPR would be if you use 0.5 as a threshold, you model splits your samples perfectly but the positive ones have scores between 0.2 and 0.4 and your negative ones have scores between 0 and 0.2.

Comment: That example just lands you in the corner of the ROC box though...

Comment: yes, I know, but what's the issue with the argument?

Comment: You're right that AUC=1 and "bad" FPR is possible, and the example works to that end, but the resulting point in ROC space isn't "bad"; the two corners will always be hit.
(Actually, I think  your example gives TPR=0, not FPR>0, but whatever.  You could also construct an example with e.g. FPR=0 and TPR=0.5, etc.)
To have AUC=1, you need every threshold to give a point in ROC space with either FPR=0 or TPR=1.  You can't get _both_ FPR>0 and TPR<1 and get perfect auROC as in OP, I think.

Comment: I need to write it down haha, thanks for your comment. I don't understand what you mean by bad point in ROC space, though. I just wanted to illustrate that you can have a good ROC curve but bad positive rate and negative metrics if a bad threshold is chosen

Comment: FPR and TPR  values per thersholds
RandomF =https://imgur.com/NsR2HEy
AdaBoost=https://imgur.com/uD77mHj