# confused AUC ROC score

Tags: classification, cross-validation, random-forest, auc

I am working on binary classification problem, I try to evaluate the performance of some classification algorithms (**LR,Decission Tree , Random forest** ...). I am using a **10 fold cross-validation** technique (to avoid over-fitting) with **AUC ROC** as scoring function to compare the performance of the algorithms, but I am getting a weird results with **Random forest** and **AdbBoost**, I have a perfect **AUC_ROC** score (i.e. =1) despite the fact that the **Recall**(TPR) and **FPR** of this algorithms are different from 1 and 0 respectively .

[image: results]

Comment: Duplicate of [Confused AUC ROC score](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/78032/confused-auc-roc-score)